# Updating json column along with other columns in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, eloquent

I would like to know how do you update JSON column data while there is other columns need to be updated as well.

As I saw samples in laravel website it's something like this for json column

```
DB::table('users')
            ->where('id', 1)
            ->update(['options->enabled' => true]);
```

but what about other columns?

here is what I have currently:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $order = Order::find($id);
        $this->validate($request, array(
            'payment_id'=>'nullable',
            'orderstatus_id' => 'required|numeric',
            'address_id' => 'required|numeric',
        ));

        $order = Order::where('id',$id)->first();
        $order->payment_id = $request->input('payment_id');
        $order->orderstatus_id = $request->input('orderstatus_id');
        $order->address_id = $request->input('address_id');

        $order->save();

        return redirect()->route('orders.index',
            $order->id)->with('success',
            'Order updated successfully.');
    }
```

and I have column named `product_name` which is Json type column and in it I have data such sample below, where I want to edit `quantity` of products inside that for example.

```
{"29": {"id": 29, "name": "effewf", "price": 24524, "quantity": 3, "attributes": [], "conditions": []}, "37": {"id": 37, "name": "test product", "price": 456346, "quantity": 2, "attributes": [], "conditions": []}}
```

As you can see in this order I have 2 products, one with quantity of `3` and another with quantity of `2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Laravel documentation has a section on [arrays and JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting). The way to do this would be to add the `$casts` property to your `Order` model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'product_name' => 'array',
];
```

In your blade views and controllers, you should be able to then access `$order->product_name` directly - no more need for doing any `json_decode()` calls.

When updating specific values, in your 'edit order' view, you'll probably want to have your form inputs named something similar to make it easy to map your updates, i.e. something similar to:

```
@foreach($order->product_name as $data) 
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      name="product_name[{{ $data['id'] }}][name]"
      value="{{ $data['name'] }}"
    >

    <label>Price:</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      name="product_name[{{ $data['id'] }}][price]"
      value="{{ $data['price'] }}"
    >

    <label>Quantity:</label>
    <input
      type="number"
      name="product_name[{{ $data['id'] }}][quantity]"
      value="{{ $data['quantity'] }}"
    >
@endforeach
```

This means that in your controller's `update()` method, you can use the new values fetched from the request input like normal. If you want to strictly follow the format from the documentation, you should also set it in a new variable rather than setting it directly, i.e.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $order = Order::find($id);

    // ... other usual stuff

    // get original data
    $new_product_name = $order->product_name;

    // contains all the inputs from the form as an array
    $input_product_name = $request->input('product_name');
    // loop over the product array
    foreach ($input_product_name as $data_id => $data) {
        // loop over each input for the product in the view form
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
             // set the new value
             $new_product_name[$data_id][$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    // set the new data (should automatically serialize into JSON for storage)
    $order->product_name = $new_product_name;

    $order->save();
}
```

Comment: The code above works but there is isuue when I save my data except updating value it will add another one,  take a look at quantity  `{"id": 29, "name": "effewf", "price": 24524, "quantity": 3, "'quantity'": "1", "attributes": [], "conditions": []}`

Comment: @mafortis had left single quotes in the input names by mistake - have removed them in my answer, should work now. If you want to make sure that price and quantity are integer values, you will need to either use `type="number"` inputs, or instead of doing a loop over `$data`, explicitly set each key so you can `int`-cast where you need to.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this is to create a model and a table for this data.

But if you want to use JSON, you can use the [`casts`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) property in the model:

```
protected $casts = [
    'product_name' => 'array',
];
```

Then, you'll be able to work with options as with an array:

```
$order = Order::where('id',$id)->first();
$order->payment_id = $request->input('payment_id');
$order->orderstatus_id = $request->input('orderstatus_id');
$order->address_id = $request->input('address_id');
$order->product_name[$request->product_id]['quantity'] = $request->new_product_quantity);
$order->save();
```

If you don't want to use casts, you can convert data manually:

```
$order->product_name = json_encode(
    json_decode($order->product_name, true)[$request->some_product_id]['quantity'] = $request->new_quantity
);
```

Comment: as I use `json_decode` in order to fetch my data if I use `casts` in my model i get error of `json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given` but if except `'product_name' => 'array',` i use `'product_name' => '',` I still can get my results with no error, would that be a problem to use `empty` for casts instead of array?

Comment: @mafortis `casts` will automatically convert JSON to an array and then the array to JSON before saving to DB. So, you don't need to use `json_decode()` or `json_encode()`

Comment: no, you didn't get my point. The thing is if I add that array in my model I MUST change all my functions and blades code to get again what I'm getting currently. so is that a problem to use just `''` instead of `'array'` ?

Comment: @mafortis if you're currently using `json_decode()` everywhere, just do not use `casts` and do this manually `json_encode(json_decode($order->product_name), true)[$request->some_product_id]['quantity'] = $request->new_quantity)`. But it's som much better to use `casts`.

Comment: ok, would you mind edit your code with the answer you gave me just now? and please to be clear to me if you can explain where this `$request->product_id` & `new_product_quantity` came from? also what should be the name of my input in blade for validation?

Comment: @mafortis add the code. `$request->product_id` is just an example. Put the real source of the data and quantity instead of these examples.

Comment: not sure how it works exactly but have such this in my edit function `$order->product_name = json_encode(json_decode($order->product_name), true)[$request->$order->id]['quantity'] = $request->new_quantity;` and get this error `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: @mafortis remove one `)`. Updated the code in the answer.

Comment: well now I have trouble with loading my json data. before in blade i used like https://gist.github.com/robertnicjoo/98288dd1d3a97257a5e7e8802fd4ea3d and I could get data now I cannot.

Comment: Please show results for `dd($order->product_name);` if you put it right before `$order->save();`